# Efficient Redux reducers, avoiding unnecessary object copies

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, functor, redux

I guess my question could also summed up as something like

> Is there an idiomatic ES6 way to have:
>
> `array.map(identity) === array` ?
>
> `array.filter(i => true) === array` ?
>
> `{obj..., attr: obj.attr} === obj` ?

I know, it has not been implemented like that in ES6, but is there some possible syntax I'm missing or simple helper functions to have these properties true without resorting to an immutable lib?

---

I use Babel and new JS features, with immutable js objects.

I would like to know how to make my reducers more efficient and generate less unnecessary object copies

I'm not interested in a lib (Mori/ImmutableJS) solution.

I have a reducer that manages a paginated list.

The `pages` attribute is actually an `Array[Array[item]]`

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  pages: [],
  allStamplesLoaded: false
};

function reducer(state = initialState, event) {
  
  switch (event.name) {

    case Names.STAMPLE_DELETED:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: removeStampleFromPages(state.pages,event.data.stampleId)
      };

    case Names.STAMPLE_UPDATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: updateStampleInPages(state.pages,event.data.apiStample)
      };

    case Names.STAMPLE_PAGES_CLEANED:
      return {
        ...initialState,
      };

    case Names.STAMPLE_PAGE_REQUESTED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };

    case Names.STAMPLE_PAGE_LOADED:
      const {stamplePage,isLastPage} = event.data;
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        pages: [...state.pages, stamplePage],
        isLastPage: isLastPage
      };

    case Names.STAMPLE_PAGE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I also have these helper functions:

```
function removeStampleFromPages(pages,deletedStampleId) {
  return pages.map(page => {
    return page.filter(apiStample => apiStample != deletedStampleId)
  })
}
function updateStampleInPages(pages,newApiStample) {
  return pages.map(page => {
    return updateStampleInPage(page,newApiStample);
  })
}
function updateStampleInPage(page,newApiStample) {
  return page.map(apiStample => {
    if (apiStample.id === newApiStample.id) {
      return newApiStample;
    }
    else {
      return apiStample;
    }
  })
}
```

---

As you can notice, everytime an event such as `STAMPLE_UPDATED` is fired, then my reducer always return a new state, with a new array of array of pages, even if none of the items of the array were actually updated. This creates unnecessary object copying and GC.

I don't wan to optimize this prematurely nor introduce an immutable library in my app, but I'd like to know if there are any idiomatic ES6 ways to solve this problem?

Comment: It works this way because that's how the methods are defined. ES6 does not provide an alternative or anything that help here.

Comment: Are you maybe over-concerned about optimizing here?  Have you tried benchmarking your reducers to see if this takes too long, or done memory profiling to see if this is truly a memory problem?

Comment: I think there’s a niche for a library that does exactly this.

Comment: I'll probably do this when I'll focus on optimizing my app then :)

Answer (score 1):

Immutable data structures such as Immutable.js and Mori use a clever trick to avoid recreating the whole structure all the time.

The strategy is fairly simple: when you update a property drill down to the property, change it and rewrap all the property from this node till the root.

Let's assume you want to change the property `c` to `4` in the following state:

```
const state1 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    },
    d: [2, 3, 4],
    e: 'Hello'
  }
}
```

The first step is to update `c` to `4`. After that you need to create

1. a new object for `b` (because `c` changed)
2. a new object for `a` (because `b` changed)
3. and new object for the state (because `a` changed).

Your new state will look like this (a `*` next to an object means the object has been recreated)

```
const state2 = *{
  a: *{
    b: *{
      c: 4
    },
    d: [2, 3, 4],
    e: 'Hello'
  }
}
```

Notice how `d` and `e` have not been touched.

You can now verify things are properly working:

```
state1 === state2 // false
state1.a === state2.a // false
state1.a.b === state2.a.b //false
state1.d === state2.d // true
state1.e === state2.e // true
```

You may notice that `d` and `e` are shared between `state1` and `state2`.

You could use a similar strategy to share information in your state without recreating a whole new state all the time.

As for your initial question:

```
array.map(identity) !== array
array.filter(i => true) !== array
{obj..., attr: obj.attr} !== obj
```

the answer is very simple.

When an array or an object is created, the Javascript VM assigns internally an identifier to that object. The identifier is incremental, so no two arrays/objects are alike.

When you perform an identity check on arrays or objects, only the internal identifier is checked for a match.

```
a = [] // internal identifier 1
[] // internal identifier to 2
b = [] // internal identifier 3
a === b // id 1 === id 3 is FALSE!
a === a // id 1 === id 1 is TRUE!
```

Comment: I know how immutable structures and identity comparison work I'm looking for a way to solve the described usecase not an explaination on why `{obj..., attr: obj.attr} !== obj`. I rewrote my question to make it more clear